# Is there an easy way to send SCSI passthrough on OSX using native python

Tags: python, macos

On Windows I am able to sent SCSI passthrough to devices using win32file.DeviceIOControl(..), on UN*X I can do it using fnctl.ioctl(...).

I have been searching for something equivalent in OSX that would allow me to send the IOCTL commands using only native python.

I would to send commands to hard drives specifically, not USB devices.

Is there anyway to do it without writing a Kernel Extension or any other code using only standard python libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw [this blog post](http://wagerlabs.com/blog/2008/02/04/writing-a-mac-osx-usb-device-driver-that-implements-scsi-pass-through/) recently talking about using SCSI passthrough under OS X.  Looks like it isn't as easy as Windows or Unix